# Change SelectedIndex without triggering SelectedIndexChanged?

Tags: xaml, combobox, windows-store-apps

I'm having a problem. I want to set a default value (kind of like a 'header text') for a ComboBox. This is purely aesthetics purposes and will describe to the user initial purpose of combobox.

I also have an SelectedIndexChanged for the combobox that opens another View.

My problem is, I change the .SelectedIndex to the '0' value so my 'Header' is selected. When I change to another Index, it seems to cause an infinite loop, until the .SelectedValue of the ComboBox becomes null and the .SelectedIndex becomes '-1' which throws an exception.

My code is below:

```
public MyView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Load += MyLoadEvent();
    }

private void MyLoadEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

private void myComboBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    { // Use ComboBox Value and Go to the Other View }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip first event by adding some flag variable. To skip first one or any next event after setting `processEvent` to `false`:

```
public MyView()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();
  Load += MyLoadEvent();
  processEvent = false;
}
...
private void myComboBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, selectionChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
   if ( processEvent )
   {
    // Use ComboBox Value and Go to the Other View 
    // event processing  
    ...
   }
   processEvent = true;
}
```